# Hong Kong overstay and chinese visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, china

I've been removed (Removed, not depported) from Hong Kong almost 2 years ago for overstaying 3 months due to health reasons. I've just received an offer to work in China so that I must apply for a Z visa (working visa) and I have already received the invitation letter and other documents issued by a chinese entity. Will my past in Hong Kong affect my application for chinese visa? I'm from Brasil btw. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about moving to another country long-term are off-topic, here, and need to be asked at [expatriates.se]. However, I'm not sure there's anything useful anyone can say. Nobody knows what the outcome of your visa application will be until you apply for it.